# Calculate count of a column based on other column in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe like below having patients stay in ICU (in hours) that is shown by ICULOS.

```
df # Main dataframe
dfy = df.copy()
```

##### dfy

| P_ID | ICULOS | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 3 | 9 |
| 2 | 4 | 9 |
| 2 | 5 | 9 |
| 2 | 6 | 9 |
| 2 | 7 | 9 |
| 2 | 8 | 9 |
| 2 | 9 | 9 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 7 |
| 4 | 2 | 7 |
| 4 | 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 | 7 |
| 4 | 6 | 7 |
| 4 | 7 | 7 |

I calculated their ICULOS Count and placed in the new column named **Count** using the code:

```
dfy['Count'] = dfy.groupby(['P_ID'])['ICULOS'].transform('count')
```

Now, I want to remove those patients based on P_ID whose Count is less than 8. (Note, I want to remove whole patient record). So, after removing the patients with Count < 8, Only the P_ID = 2 will remain as the count is 9.

The desired output:

| P_ID | ICULOS | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 3 | 9 |
| 2 | 4 | 9 |
| 2 | 5 | 9 |
| 2 | 6 | 9 |
| 2 | 7 | 9 |
| 2 | 8 | 9 |
| 2 | 9 | 9 |

I tried the following code, but for some reason, it is not working for me. It did worked for me but when I re-run the code after few days, it is giving me **0 result**. Can someone suggest a better code? Thanks.

```
dfy = dfy.drop_duplicates(subset=['P_ID'],keep='first')
lis1 = dfy['P_ID'].tolist()
Icu_less_8 = dfy.loc[dfy['Count'] < 8]
lis2 = Icu_less_8.P_ID.to_list()
lis_3  = [k for k in tqdm_notebook(lis1) if k not in lis2]
# removing those patients who have ICULOS of less than 8 hours
df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
for l in tqdm_notebook(lis_3, desc = 'Progress'):
    df_1 = df_1.append(df.loc[df['P_ID']==l])
```

Comment: if `dfy` is the dataframe after the transform operation, all you have to do is simple boolean masking. `dfy = dfy[dfy['count'] >= 8]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly filter rows in transform using [`Series.ge`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-ge/#:%7E:text=Pandas%20series.ge()%20is,caller%20series%20%3E%3D%20other%20series.):

```
In [1521]: dfy[dfy.groupby(['P_ID'])['ICULOS'].transform('count').ge(8)]
Out[1521]: 
    P_ID  ICULOS  Count
5      2       1      9
6      2       2      9
7      2       3      9
8      2       4      9
9      2       5      9
10     2       6      9
11     2       7      9
12     2       8      9
13     2       9      9
```

**EDIT after OP's comment:** For multiple conditions, do:

```
In [1533]: x = dfy.groupby(['P_ID'])['ICULOS'].transform('count')
In [1539]: dfy.loc[x[x.ge(8) & x.le(72)].index]
Out[1539]: 
    P_ID  ICULOS  Count
5      2       1      9
6      2       2      9
7      2       3      9
8      2       4      9
9      2       5      9
10     2       6      9
11     2       7      9
12     2       8      9
13     2       9      9
```

Comment: What does this ```gt()``` means? Is it greater than? Or something else?

Comment: `gt: greater than`

Comment: ok. please let me try it

Comment: should be `.ge(8)` according to description in question I think

Comment: @timgeb Makes sense. Updated the answer.

Comment: Ok. So if I want to remove those patients from my dataframe ```dfy``` whose Count is more than 72, how I can do that? Like I want to apply 2 conditions. Remove patients with Count < 8 and Count > 72.

Comment: @Optimus Please check the 2nd part of my answer.

Comment: tysm for the answer :)